# I cant import any python modules, and cant install any modules with pip either

Tags: python, import, module, pip

when I try to import any module that I installed with pip3, the system just sends me tons of texts. I am sorry I can't specify any better, but I am new to python and ubuntu. I tried the command pip3 list and then I get this:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
```

And after that, I get the list with some packages and their versions. And the packages that I remember installing don't appear in the list, like `NumPy` or `random`. I am using `python 3.8` and `pip 3`.

Everything was perfect, but I tried to install the visual or python module, and after that, I got that error. I think I tried to install the modules with pip and after with conda. And I have no ideia in what to do.

Comment: I think you're trying to do things with the system python. Do you know about virtual environments? That might be a better approach.

Comment: Always use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` (instead of `pip` or `pip3`, etc.) https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try upgrading the cryptography library, something like this:

```
pip install cryptography==3.3.2
```