# Unable to install/uninstall with pip due to CryptographyDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, import, module, pip

I get this warning when installing with both pip3 and pip

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
```

I've seen this post ([I cant import any python modules, and cant install any modules with pip either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014506/i-cant-import-any-python-modules-and-cant-install-any-modules-with-pip-either)), but upgrading cryptography doesn't work. Same warning come up.

I've tried pip -v and pip3 -v, they works fine. I've also reinstalled pip, but no magic happens.

**Edit for future reference**: 
It correctly upgrade the module now after a few minutes, tho i'm still not sure why it took so long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cant import any python modules, and cant install any modules with pip either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014506/i-cant-import-any-python-modules-and-cant-install-any-modules-with-pip-either)

Comment: @gijswijs No, same warning comes up

Comment: @gijswijs It correctly upgrade the module now after a few minutes, tho i'm still not sure why it took so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, install cryptography version 3.3.2

```
pip install cryptography==3.3.2
```

Comment: same warning comes up

Comment: It correctly upgrade the module now after a few minutes, tho i'm still not sure why it took so long.

Comment: People who will use this solution you need to make share that it is not breaking any other working apps depending on other version of cryptography